# How can a mailing address in a database be encoded into a double

Tags: database, ms-access, encoding, double

I have an MDB database which holds information about patients (customers). I am trying to understand how the practice management system which controls the database works, however, when I look at the database schema, the 'Mailing Address' field is of type 'double' and the data shows a number such as "1.0814000000000000e+04" which represents the address "1 John Smith Road" with "SOMETOWN" as the suburb (a separate field in the application, but with no corresponding field in the database, which makes me assume that they are all bundled together), "QLD" as the region and "1111" as the postcode.

Does anyone have a clue as to how this information becomes a double and if so, how might I go about reconstructing it as an address?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a foreign key? Even if one were to store a string data as a double precision float, the typical double is 8 bytes long, which means a max of 8 ASCII characters.

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma I am quite new to databases in general, so do you mean 'foreign key' as in a key that relates to another table in the database (which actually holds the information). If so, I also thought that but cannot find any tables in the database that could possibly hold that sort of information... this is very confusing...

Comment: @ofrye Yes, that is what I mean. They are normally integers, but any data type could be used. What is MDB? Microsoft Access? If so, you should add such a tag to your question.

Comment: @DondiMichaelStroma I take back my previous comment, it appears that the double is a key to another table which uses an integer field 'ID' so somewhere along the line, the program is converting the double to an integer... Is there any reason why a program would do this instead of just using integers on both tables? Also, what should I do to my question (close, answer, etc...) because i'm new here...

Comment: @ofrye That seems like a good guess as 1.0814000000000000e+04 is actually an integer (10814) even though it's stored as a double float. Not sure what you should do with the question, I write my comments as an answer, and you can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing string data as a double seems unlikely, as the maximum length would be 8 characters (a double is usually 8 bytes, and one ASCII character = one byte). My guess would be a foreign key. 1.0814000000000000e+04 = 1.0814x10<sup>4</sup> = 10814 which is an integer. No idea why it's stored like that though.